# What is the font used in the Park Avenue logo?

Tags: logo, font-identification, branding

What is the font used or what is a similar font to the one used in the Park Avenue logo?

[image: Park Avenue logo]

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [Averes Title](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/reserves/averes-title/) from MyFonts but bold version.

[image]

Or [Contax Pro](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typeinnovations/contax-pro/) via MyFonts:

[image: CONTAX]